# LoadingButton removed from MUI?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

LoadingButton component not found in mui modules
i tried this import

```
import LoadingButton from '@mui/lab/LoadingButton';
```

but i get an error that says module not found

Comment: "@material-ui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.44", "@mui/material": "^5.0.4",

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the correct package name and version for `material-ui`.
In your `package.json` you should change:

```
"@material-ui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.44",
```

to

```
"@mui/lab": "5.0.0-alpha.51",
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-banzai-v9ynv) for a live working `LoadingButton` component example.